# attempt to call global 'BlocK' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I've tried in similar way to sample code cifar.torch/nin.lua

but no matter how i tried w/wo local, the error message is 'Attempt to call global 'Block'(a nil value)'

how can i solve this? help me.

```
local function Block(...)
  local arg = {...}
  model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(...))
  model:add(nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(arg[2],1e-3))
  model:add(nn.ReLU(true))
  return model
end

local function createModel()
  Block(3,64,3,3,1,1)
  model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))
  Block(64,128,3,3,1,1)
  model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))
  Block(128,256,3,3,1,1)
  Block(256,256,3,3,1,1)
  model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))
  Block(256,512,3,3,1,1)
  BlocK(512,512,3,3,1,1)
  model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))
  BlocK(512,512,3,3,1,1)
  BlocK(512,512,3,3,1,1)
  model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))
  return model
end

createModel()
print(model)
```

Answer (score 4):

Lua is case sensitive.

Bloc**k** is not the same as Bloc**K**

You have several function calls ending with captial K

You have to call Bloc**k** as you  never defined a function Bloc**K**

Bloc**K** is nil

Comment: Oops i didn't know it. Thanks.
and I'd like to return a model in other file as train.lua
how can i get the model? when i print out in train.lua, it is still nil.(i made out 'Block' problem, and when i printed out in that file, it came out in right way)

Answer (score 1):

> Block(256,512,3,3,1,1)
>   BlocK(512,512,3,3,1,1)

Lua is case sensitive, but you have lines that calls 'Block' as 'BlocK'. Those will fail.

Comment: Thanks. Then how can i call the model in other file? 
e.g.  in train.lua, i set " local model = require 'model.lua' " and i print out the model, but it's still nil. it seems like a problem with local and global

Comment: Normally you don't 'requre "model.lua"' on every model creation. Instead you should make createModel() accessible from outside. Either return that function as last statement of mode.lua, or put it in global environment, possibly within table associated for model-related services. You can return model itself only if there will be single instance of such model.